# Determine the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{4n^2-2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+4}} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{4n^2-2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+4}}.$$

**Answer**

Ratio test fails.

Also I can't apply comparison test.

**Any idea is really appreciating .**

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2-2}}{\sqrt{9n^2+4}}=\Big[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-2}{9n^2+4}\Big]^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{3}\neq 0$$
the series diverges by the limit test.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator goes like
$2n$
and the denominator goes like
$3n$
so their ratio goes like
2/3.

The terms themselves converge
(to 2/3),
but tis causes their sum
to diverge
(so the sum of $m$ terms
is about $2m/3$).